# CSS Keyframes controlled with Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I would like to control the following animations with JS/Jquery rather than CSS hover action. Is it possible?

```css
.button {
  width: 350px;
  height: 300px;
  margin: 100px auto;
  position: relative;
  border: solid 2px #cbd4d9;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px;
  border-radius: 5px;
}




.button:hover .hoverBtn:before, .button:hover .hoverBtn:after {
  opacity: 1;
  -webkit-animation: open 0.8s;
  /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
  animation: open 0.8s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.39, 0.575, 0.565, 1);
  animation-direction: normal;
}
.button:hover .hoverBtn-bottom:before, .button:hover .hoverBtn-bottom:after {
  opacity: 1;
  -webkit-animation: openB 0.8s;
  /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
  animation: openB 0.8s;
  animation-delay: 0.8s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.39, 0.575, 0.565, 1);
  animation-direction: normal;
}

.hoverBtn {
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
  position: absolute;
  top: -1px;
}
.hoverBtn:before {
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  height: 0;
  width: 0;
  display: block;
  opacity: 0;
  border-top: solid 2px #517180;
  border-left: solid 2px #517180;
  -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 5px;
  -moz-border-top-left-radius: 5px;
  border-top-left-radius: 5px;
  -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
  -moz-border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
  right: 175px;
}
.hoverBtn:after {
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  height: 0;
  width: 0;
  display: block;
  opacity: 0;
  border-top: solid 2px #517180;
  border-right: solid 2px #517180;
  -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 5px;
  -moz-border-top-right-radius: 5px;
  border-top-right-radius: 5px;
  -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
  -moz-border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
  left: 175px;
}

.hoverBtn-bottom {
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
  position: absolute;
}
.hoverBtn-bottom:before {
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  height: 0;
  width: 0;
  display: block;
  opacity: 0;
  height: 300px;
  border-bottom: solid 2px #517180;
  -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 5px;
  -moz-border-top-right-radius: 5px;
  border-top-right-radius: 5px;
  -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
  -moz-border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
  right: 0;
}
.hoverBtn-bottom:after {
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  height: 0;
  width: 0;
  display: block;
  opacity: 0;
  height: 300px;
  border-bottom: solid 2px #517180;
  -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 5px;
  -moz-border-top-left-radius: 5px;
  border-top-left-radius: 5px;
  -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
  -moz-border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
  left: 0;
}


@keyframes open {
  0% {
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
  }
  50% {
    width: 175px;
    height: 0;
  }
  100% {
    width: 175px;
    height: 300px;
  }
}
@keyframes openB {
  0% {
    width: 0px;
  }
  100% {
    width: 175px;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" >
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Square border animation</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
</head>

<body>



<div id="target">
  Click here
</div>


  <div id="myButton" class="button">
    <a href="#">
        <div class="hoverBtn"></div>
        <div class="hoverBtn-bottom"></div>
     </a>
  </div>
  <script>
$( "#target" ).click(function() {
  alert( "Handler for .click() called." );
});
</script>
  
</body>
</html>
```

All code has now been provided.

I am looking to use JS/jquery to initiate the animation that is currently initiated on hover.

I have tried some of the soultions below but not sure how to implement the class changes.

Regards,

Jonathan.

Comment: Define "control"?

Comment: As in be able to use JS/jquery to call a function that would instigate the animation. Either on a timed event etc.

Comment: You could always have jquery add a class to the element, and have the keyframes css rule be dependent upon that class.

Comment: Apologies but I am not the greatest at CSS and JS. Are you able to elaborate a bit more?

Comment: So I assume some where you have something like `.element:hover { animation: open; }` since you said hover in your question.  The point is the `.element:hover` part is the selector for the elements to apply the rule to.  That can be anything.  Including something like `.element.anotherclass`.  Which would happen for any object that has the `element` class and the `anotherclass` class.  Then all you have to do with javascript is change elements to have both those classes, or match whatever css selector you put on that rule.

Comment: That makes sense! I shall try that and report back. Thanks

Comment: I have provided all code as I cannot get it to work still

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before I start off I wrote this in vanila js since I'm not that familiar with jquery out of my head, if you realy want I can search the jquery syntax but for now at least grasp the concept.

The basic thing you've got to do is the following structure

```
var button = document.querySelector('#myButton');
if(button.classList.contains('animBorder')){
    button.classList.remove('animBorder');
}else{ 
    button.classList.add('animBorder');
}
```

You will need to change the :hover for a class (in my example named '.animBorder') then check onclick whether the class is active or not, and add/remove the class correspondingly.

Let me know If you need more explaining, I'll edit.

Here is a running example:

```js
function _$(str){ return document.querySelector(str); }

_$('#target').addEventListener('click', doClick);

function doClick(e){
  var bcl = _$('#myButton').classList
  bcl[bcl.contains('animBorder')?'remove':'add']('animBorder');
}
```

```css
.button {
  width: 350px;
  height: 300px;
  margin: 100px auto;
  position: relative;
  border: solid 2px #cbd4d9;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
.button.animBorder .hoverBtn:before, 
.button.animBorder .hoverBtn:after {
  opacity: 1;
  -webkit-animation: open 0.8s;
  /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
  animation: open 0.8s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.39, 0.575, 0.565, 1);
  animation-direction: normal;
}
.button.animBorder .hoverBtn-bottom:before, 
.button.animBorder .hoverBtn-bottom:after {
  opacity: 1;
  -webkit-animation: openB 0.8s;
  /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
  animation: openB 0.8s;
  animation-delay: 0.8s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.39, 0.575, 0.565, 1);
  animation-direction: normal;
}
.hoverBtn {
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
  position: absolute;
  top: -1px;
}
.hoverBtn:before {
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  height: 0;
  width: 0;
  display: block;
  opacity: 0;
  border-top: solid 2px #517180;
  border-left: solid 2px #517180;
  -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 5px;
  -moz-border-top-left-radius: 5px;
  border-top-left-radius: 5px;
  -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
  -moz-border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
  right: 175px;
}
.hoverBtn:after {
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  height: 0;
  width: 0;
  display: block;
  opacity: 0;
  border-top: solid 2px #517180;
  border-right: solid 2px #517180;
  -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 5px;
  -moz-border-top-right-radius: 5px;
  border-top-right-radius: 5px;
  -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
  -moz-border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
  left: 175px;
}
.hoverBtn-bottom {
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
  position: absolute;
}
.hoverBtn-bottom:before {
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  height: 0;
  width: 0;
  display: block;
  opacity: 0;
  height: 300px;
  border-bottom: solid 2px #517180;
  -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 5px;
  -moz-border-top-right-radius: 5px;
  border-top-right-radius: 5px;
  -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
  -moz-border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
  right: 0;
}
.hoverBtn-bottom:after {
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  height: 0;
  width: 0;
  display: block;
  opacity: 0;
  height: 300px;
  border-bottom: solid 2px #517180;
  -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 5px;
  -moz-border-top-left-radius: 5px;
  border-top-left-radius: 5px;
  -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
  -moz-border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
  left: 0;
}
@keyframes open {
  0% {
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
  }
  50% {
    width: 175px;
    height: 0;
  }
  100% {
    width: 175px;
    height: 300px;
  }
}
@keyframes openB {
  0% {
    width: 0px;
  }
  100% {
    width: 175px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="target">Click here</div>
<div id="myButton" class="button">
  <a href="#">
      <div class="hoverBtn"></div>
      <div class="hoverBtn-bottom"></div>
   </a>
</div>
```